# How does OpenSSH LogLevel option work?

Tags: ssh, openssh

I have the following network topology:

```
workstation <-> network_device <-> authentication_server
```

When I log in to `network_device` from `workstation` over SSH, then `network_device` checks with TACACS+ `authentication_server` if I have a permission to log in, what are my access rights for that `network_device`, etc. When I execute `ssh -o LogLevel=quiet network_device` in `workstation`, then I do not see the network device banner, but I do see the following prompt:

```
$ ssh -o LogLevel=quiet network_device
TACACS authentication!

Password: 

$
```

This `TACACS authentication!` string is set by `authentication_server`. When I execute `ssh -vvv -o LogLevel=quiet network_device`, then I see that this banner and password prompt seem to have different [message IDs](https://www.iana.org/assignments/ssh-parameters/ssh-parameters.xhtml). Banner:

```
debug3: receive packet: type 53                    
debug3: input_userauth_banner                      

*************************************************  
*    Access limited to Authorized Users only    *  
*************************************************
```

Password prompt:

```
debug3: receive packet: type 60                        
debug2: input_userauth_info_req                        
debug2: input_userauth_info_req: num_prompts 1         
TACACS authentication!                           

Password:
```

Does OpenSSH client `LogLevel` option work in a way that it simply filters certain message IDs depending on `LogLevel` value? Manual page does not explain, how exactly `LogLevel` decides what to show:

```
 LogLevel
         Gives the verbosity level that is used when logging messages from ssh(1).  The possible values are: QUIET, FATAL, ERROR, INFO, VERBOSE, DEBUG, DEBUG1, DEBUG2, and DEBUG3.  The default is
         INFO.  DEBUG and DEBUG1 are equivalent.  DEBUG2 and DEBUG3 each specify higher levels of verbose output.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The bulk of what you want to know is in `log.c` in the OpenSSH source. There is an enum variable called `log_level`. (Enum meaning it acts like a number under the hood, but each level is associated with an easy-to-understand name.) This `log_level` variable is set globally and acts as a mask for hiding logs you aren't interested in.

Then whenever something is logged, the message is also associated with an importance level, and the message + importance are given to a function called `do_log`.

In the `do_log` function, we see the following check:

```
if (!force && level > log_level)
    return;
```

It means that if the message is less important than the configured log level, this message is elided from the log output.

The `do_log` function does additional processing, eg using the importance level of the message to decide whether to prefix the output with `fatal` or whatever is appropriate.